# Как извлечь данные из БД и присвоить их переменной(JDBC)?

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc

Необходимо извлечь данные типа int из записи в БД и присвоить переменной.
Пример:| Мука | 35 | кг |
Надо число 35 присвоить переменной int для дальнейшей работы с ним.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Что именно у вас вызывает трудности? Где пример кода который вы пытаетесь написать?

Вот простейший пример подключения и запроса к mysql.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SimpleJDBCApplication {

   static final String DB_URL =
      "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";
   static final String DB_DRV =
      "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
   static final String DB_USER = "mickey";
   static final String DB_PASSWD = "mickey";

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Connection connection = null;
      Statement statement = null;
      ResultSet resultSet = null;

      try{
         connection=DriverManager.getConnection
            (DB_URL,DB_USER,DB_PASSWD);
         statement=connection.createStatement();
         resultSet=statement.executeQuery
            ("SELECT * FROM books");
         while(resultSet.next()){
            System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\n",
            resultSet.getString(1),
            resultSet.getString(2),
            resultSet.getString(3),
            resultSet.getFloat(4));
         }

      }catch(SQLException ex){
      }finally{
         try {
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: как содержимое из resultSet присвоить, предположим, переменно String a; ?

Comment: Например так.                                                                                                                   
               `while (resultSet.next()) {
                id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                name = resultSet.getString("name");
                specialty = resultSet.getString("specialty");
                salary = resultSet.getInt("salary");                
            }`                                                                                                                   [Подробнее тут](https://proselyte.net/tutorials/jdbc/result-set/)